# Migrating a legacy java web project to Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

We have a legacy Java project which runs on a web application server (Glassfish, Tomcat).

The project does not use Spring, or any other dependency injection framework.

The plan is to migrate the project to run under Spring Boot, and to, piece by piece, upgrade or replace layers of the application so that classes become components which can run under Spring. For example, the existing managers would use the `@Service` annotation so they would become Spring components, as would the DAO classes which would be annotated with `@Repository`.

What is the best way to integrate the legacy code with Spring Boot, so that when the Spring Boot project is started, the existing code will be called as it would be if it was deployed as a war to a Tomcat server?

The basic issue is that a Spring Boot project is a Java application with an application class and a main method. The legacy project, on the other hand, is a web applications, and as such does not have a main method, at least one which is exposed in the code, so there is no Java process to start or call from Spring Boot.

One solution is to create a Spring Boot application and, module by module, add layers and classes from the old app as Spring components. That is probably the cleanest approach, but for such a big application, would take a very long time and means we would be working on two code bases, and is probably not practical.

Is there another approach?

Thanks very much

Comment: This is a very broad, opinion-based, "depends-on", non-specific and therefore [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. Every single person may come up with their ideas, library proposals, stack thoughts, structure design, web application patterns, and etc. Please have a look on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Another problem might be the UI, perhaps JSP or JSF in the legacy system?

Comment: @Twistleton yes, that is certainly a layer which needs be upgraded and eventually replaced

Comment: @user1052610 I have a similar legacy with Java 1.5, Tomcat and JSP. So far, we have simply replaced a few building blocks. And we have left the legacy system untouched.